# Tensorflow, change Tensor values given a condition

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am translating a numpy code to Tensorflow.

It has the following line:

```
netout[..., 5:] *= netout[..., 5:] > obj_threshold
```

This is not the same Tensorflow syntax, I'm having trouble finding the functions with the same behavior.

Firstly I tried:

```
netout[..., 5:] * netout[..., 5:] > obj_threshold
```

But the return is a boolean only Tensor.
In this case I want all values below the `obj_threshold` to be 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just wanted to make 0 all values below `obj_threshold` you could just do:

```
netout = tf.where(netout > obj_threshold, netout, tf.zeros_like(netout))
```

Or:

```
netout = netout * tf.cast(netout > obj_threshold, netout.dtype)
```

However, your case is a bit more complicated, because you only want the change to affect part of the tensor. So one thing you can do is make a boolean mask that is `True` for values over `obj_threshold` or values where the last index is below 5.

```
mask = (netout > obj_threshold) | (tf.range(tf.shape(netout)[-1]) < 5)
```

Then you can use that with any of the previous methods:

```
netout = tf.where(mask, netout, tf.zeros_like(netout))

netout = netout * tf.cast(mask, netout.dtype)
```